# Paypal api status pending in payment capture

Tags: javascript, api, paypal, sandbox, status

Everything is fine in the PayPal sandbox but in the live environment, there is an issue with transactions.

My js :

```
<script src="https://www.paypal.com/sdk/js?client-id=key&currency=GBP"></script>

createOrder: (data, actions) => {
console.log("create order");
return actions.order.create({
purchase_units: [{
amount: {
value: 10.00
}
}]
});
},

onApprove: (data, actions) => {
console.log("on approve");
return actions.order.capture().then(function(orderData) {

const transaction = orderData.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0];
alert(${transaction.status}: ${transaction.id});                                          
});
}
}).render('#paypal-button-container');
```

This is my API response issue:

```
"payments": {
          "captures": [
            {
              "amount": {
                "currency_code": "GBP",
                "value": "1.00"
              },
            
              "seller_protection": {
                "dispute_categories": [
                  "ITEM_NOT_RECEIVED",
                  "UNAUTHORIZED_TRANSACTION"
                ],
                "status": "ELIGIBLE"
              },
              "status": "PENDING",
              "status_details": {
                "reason": "PENDING_REVIEW"
               }


            }
          ]
        },
```

the amount is received. but it's going to hold because of this status pending. but the PayPal team provides this as the solution " As for pending payments that would be a setting on your shopping cart, the setting would need to be set as 'sale' instead of 'Authorisation' " how do set this?

Answer (score 0):

> the setting would need to be set as 'sale' instead of 'Authorisation' "

This is not your issue, this is already a capture. The reason it is pending is given as "pending review", which basically means what it says. PayPal will review and either approve or deny the transaction, usually within 24 hours.

Comment: how to avoid the "on hold" issue via payment gateway

Comment: The account owner can contact PayPal's business support to ask about it

Comment: already did. but no luck. again and again they give this is as a solution "As for pending payments that would be a setting on your shopping cart, the setting would need to be set as 'sale' instead of 'Authorisation"

Comment: No, that's not it. It's already a capture not an authorization.

Comment: yes. i updated my JavaScript in post. please check and share if you have any idea about this ?

Comment: Not an integration issue, the payment is pending at PayPal